# Getting temporary result in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I wanted to use temporary results in my pyqgis script just like

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

carte_init=processing.getObject("carte_postes")

extent = "%s,%s,%s,%s" % ( carte_init.extent().xMinimum(), 
carte_init.extent().xMaximum(), carte_init.extent().yMinimum(), 
carte_init.extent().yMaximum() )

# Exrtacting test posts centroids
postes= processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', carte_init, None)
centroides_postes=processing.runalg('qgis:polygoncentroids', 
postes['OUTPUT'], None)
voronoi_max_extent=processing.runalg('grass7:v.voronoi', 
centroides_postes['OUTPUT'], False, False, extent,  -1, 0, 0, None) }
```

But I get the following when I run it in the python console...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'OUTPUT'
```

As it works perfectly well in this script

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

layer=processing.getObject("carte")
layer.invertSelection()

tampon_plus = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', layer, 
"20","5",False, None)
dissolve = processing.runalg('qgis:dissolve', tampon_plus['OUTPUT'], True, 
None, None)
carte_finale = processing.runalg('qgis:fixeddistancebuffer', 
dissolve['OUTPUT'], "-20","5",False, 
"c:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/zones/carte_finale.shp")}
```

I wonder where is my mistake. I tried to use algorithm  ['Result'] just as in [Saving layer as temporary file usig PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222684/saving-layer-as-temporary-file-usig-pyqgis) but it's not working any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `['OUTPUT_LAYER']` instead of `['OUTPUT']`. You can see this if you type in the **Python Console**:

```
>>>import processing
>>>processing.alghelp('qgis:saveselectedfeatures')
ALGORITHM: Save selected features
    INPUT_LAYER <ParameterVector>
    OUTPUT_LAYER <OutputVector>
```

Both `qgis:saveselectedfeatures` and `qgis:polygoncentroids` algorithms require this.

---

So try running the following:

```
import processing
from qgis.core import *

carte_init=processing.getObject("carte_postes")

extent = "%s,%s,%s,%s" % ( carte_init.extent().xMinimum(), 
carte_init.extent().xMaximum(), carte_init.extent().yMinimum(), 
carte_init.extent().yMaximum() )

# Exrtacting test posts centroids
postes= processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', carte_init, None)
centroides_postes=processing.runalg('qgis:polygoncentroids', 
postes['OUTPUT_LAYER'], None)
voronoi_max_extent=processing.runalg('grass7:v.voronoi', 
centroides_postes['OUTPUT_LAYER'], False, False, extent,  -1, 0, 0, None)
```

Comment: Well saving my life once agin, I thought ['OUTPUT'] was the only way to get the output... Thans !

Comment: @Clement - Most welcome! There are three parameters of which I am aware: `['SAVENAME']`, `['OUTPUT']` and `['OUTPUT_LAYER']`. Just depends on the algorithm used. This is how processing does this. You can do this manually which was described in your link by using `processing.getObject(postes['Results'])` :)